# Display the latest document at the top of a list firestore collection, ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have a table with list of entries and currently I'm fetching data from firestore collection; anytime I add a new document to the list, it appears at the bottom, is there a way to display recently add document on my table at the top instead of the entries appearing at the bottom?

Here's to code that fetches and displays a new document to my table:-

```js
  useEffect(() =>{
// LISTEN (REALTIME)
const unsub = onSnapshot(
  collection(db, "users"),
  (snapShot) => {
    let list = [];
    snapShot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
      list.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
    });
    setData(list);
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  }
);

return () => {
  unsub();
};
}, []);
```

Here's the code that adds a new document to my table:-

```js
 const handleAdd = async(e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      // this is the add function to add a new doc
      if(isEmpty(id)){
        await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
          ...userInfo,
          timeStamp: serverTimestamp(),
        });    
      } else{
      // this is to update a list 
        await setDoc(doc(db, "users/" + id), {
          ...userInfo,
          timeStamp: serverTimestamp(),
        });    
      }
      navigate("/users")
  }
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you are getting the entries?

Comment: I've updated the question with the code snippet

Comment: I see. You can't do that we firebase, because the order in wich content are displayed depend on the sorting values you used. So when fetching data, you can match the last added by sorting data by its time written for exemple, then get the one recent before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution:-

In terms of ordering data in a list to show the latest, what you have to do is assign timestamps for all of the documents when they're newly added, then query the data to show the list by the timeStamp either in Ascending or descending order, here's the code to explain that:-

```js
 useEffect(() =>{
    // LISTEN (REALTIME)
    const collectionRef = collection(db, "users");
    const q = query(collectionRef, orderBy("timeStamp", "asc"))
    const unsub = onSnapshot(
      q,
      (snapShot) => {
        let list = [];
        snapShot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          list = [{ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }, ...list]
         
        });
        setData(list);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
    
    return () => {
      unsub();
    };
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make new data to come first in the list: by using

```
list = [{ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }, ...list]
```

whole code

```
useEffect(() =>{
// LISTEN (REALTIME)
const unsub = onSnapshot(
  collection(db, "users"),
  (snapShot) => {
    let list = [];
    snapShot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
      list = [{ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }, ...list]
     
    });
    setData(list);
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  }
);

return () => {
  unsub();
};
}, []);
```

Comment: in the React part or backend? can you share the render code?

Comment: then set it as correct answer, by putting a check on it

Comment: so that others can not that you have found the answer

Comment: It displays at different areas like unordered

Comment: I see. You can't do that we firebase, because the order in wich content are displayed depend on the sorting values you used. So when fetching data, you can match the last added by sorting data by its time written for exemple, then get the one recent before

Comment: At first, it displayed new entry at the top, then it started displaying in an unorderly manner

Comment: Then you have to order them when fetching, you can't order them when adding upp new documents

Comment: Sorting by it's time, I don't really get that, I'm showing a server timestamp in my documents on the collection

Comment: So how do I order them when fetching...

Comment: I mean you have to assign a given timestamp and then fetch docs by ordering by timestamp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253862/discussion-between-deezy-and-ingenious-hans).